Dataset not failing on validation for json schema
I have a base schema and extended schema below
./resources/json-schemas/simple-person.schema
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/json-schemas/simple-person.schema",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Simple Person",
  "type": "object",
  "people": {
    "items": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The person's name."
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The person's age."
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "age"
      ]
    }
  }
}

./extended-person.schema
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/extended-person.schema",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Extended Person",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "http://example.com/json-schemas/simple-person.schema"
    },
    {
      "people": {
        "items": {
          "properties": {
            "height": {
              "type": "number",
              "description": "The person's height in centimeters."
            },
            "required": [
              "height"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

I then have an instance of this dataset that I want to validate against.
./person-dataset.json
{
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": 25,
            "new value": "value"
        }
    ]
}

I would expect the validation to fail, but it passes with the code below
from pathlib import Path

import json

from referencing import Registry, Resource
from referencing.exceptions import NoSuchResource
from jsonschema import Draft202012Validator


def retrieve_from_filesystem(uri: str):
    SCHEMAS = Path("./resources/json-schemas/")

    if uri.startswith("http://example.com/json-schemas/"):
        path = SCHEMAS / Path(uri.removeprefix("http://example.com/json-schemas/"))
    else:
        raise NoSuchResource(ref=uri)

    contents = json.loads(path.read_text())

    return Resource.from_contents(contents)

registry = Registry(retrieve=retrieve_from_filesystem)

schema = json.load(Path("./extended-person.schema").open())
instance = json.load(Path("./person-dataset.json").open())
validator = Draft202012Validator(schema, registry=registry)

validator.validate(instance)

I expected this to fail for two reasons

no "height" property is included in the dataset
a new property "new value" is included in the dataset that isn't specified in the schemas

How do I fix this to make it so datasets like this will fail?

This one is a bit tricky in that you are adding constraints to an existing schema inside of a nested array

define the extension with properties>people>items
add your new keyword definition for height
inside of items you need to $ref the nested schema in the simple-person.schema where you are adding a new keyword
add unevaluatedProperties: false which allows you to see into the reference schema to understand name and age are defined, and also to allow height but, not any additional properties.

{
    "$id": "http://example.com/json-schemas/extended-person.schema",
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "people": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "unevaluatedProperties": false,
                "$ref": "simple-person.schema#/properties/people/items",
                "properties": {
                    "height": {
                        "type": "number"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "height"
                ]
            }
        },
    "required": ["people"]
    }
}


this is a great reference for modeling inheritance. JSON Schema doesn't completely support inheritance, but there are definitely ways to model it very close to the expected behavior with some concessions.
https://json-schema.org/blog/posts/modelling-inheritance

p.s. $ref is now allowed at the root of a schema, alongside sibling keywords such as properties or other applicators(except another $ref) which allows you to simplify your schema from using allOf to compose multiple schemas in this fashion

I'm not sure why, but I get an error in the referencing with your extended schema and not the one that I posted below. File "/Users/cameronzabriskie/SEED/zontal-ontologies/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/referencing/jsonschema.py", line 50, in _dollar_id     return contents.get("$id") AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Share the $id of your two schemas to see how the base uri is defined

I figured it out. Thanks  for the great answer!

It looks like you have to be super strict in where you place properties. To get the desired behavior, I had to update my files like so...
./resources/json-schemas/simple-person.schema
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/json-schemas/simple-person.schema",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Simple Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "people": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "The person's name."
          },
          "age": {
            "type": "integer",
            "description": "The person's age."
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "name",
          "age"
        ]
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "people"
    ]
  }
}

./extended-person.schema
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/extended-person.schema",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Extended Person",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "http://example.com/json-schemas/simple-person.schema"
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "people": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "height": {
                "type": "number",
                "description": "The person's height in centimeters."
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "height"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

This will make the following dataset fail, because it doesn't have the required "height" parameter specified in the extension
{
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": 25
        }
    ]
}

However, apparently you cannot specify there will be no other parameters without redefining the requirements. So my extension can change to
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/extended-person.schema",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Extended Person",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "http://example.com/json-schemas/simple-person.schema"
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "people": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "height": {
                "type": "number",
                "description": "The person's height in centimeters."
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "name",
              "age",
              "height"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Then the following dataset will fail
{
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": 25,
            "height": 145,
            "new value": "new value"
        }
    ]
}

I don't really like that I have to redefine the required properties in the extension. If there is a workaround to this, I would be interested in knowing.
